# D_4 cannot be written as direct product of groups A x B.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that none of the following groups is a direct product of groups (A x B).

(a) D_4 , with cardinality 8

(b) D_5,  with cardinality 10.

Attempt: We need to show for (a) that D_4 is not isomorphic to a direct product (A x B).
We know |D_4| = 8 , and that D_4 is not abelian.

For (A x B) to be isomorphic to D_4, (A x B) has to have cardinality 8 also.

But the only groups of order 8 that can be written as a product are Z_4 x Z_2, however, even though |Z_4 x Z_2| = 8 also.

Z_4 x Z_2 is abelian, but we know that if a group is isomorphic to a direct product, then it must be abelian, thus we get a contradiction since D_4 is not abelian.

Proof (b) is similarly.
Please can anyone please give me feedback, if part (a) is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: May I use the trivial group as one of the factors?

Comment: I don't know which trivial group you refer?

Comment: The group consisting only of an identity element is the trivial group.  At some point you will need to use neither $A$ nor $B$ is the trivial group in your proof, so it's best to state this as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach is sound, but you are skipping some cases.  Perhaps organizing the material more systematically will help.

You are essentially saying that since $D_4$ has order $8$, the product of the orders of any $A,B$ that would be direct "factors" $D_4 = A \times B$ must also be $8$.

The trivial group $\{e\}$ has order one, and $D_4 = D_4 \times \{e\}$ corresponds to the factorization $8 = 8 \times 1$.  Other than this "trivial" solution, there is no way to write the dihedral group $D_4$ as a direct product.  One way to use this restriction (that neither of $A,B$ are the trivial group) is to require the orders of $A,B$ to be (factors of $8$) greater than one.

Now the possibilities are narrowed, because the only orders that work (up to swapping $A,B$) are $8 = 4 \times 2$.

As you've observed that $D_4$ is *not* abelian, the fact that the direct product of abelian groups is again abelian will make short work of eliminating possibilities.